# How to get SUM and AVG from a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but none of the answers I found solve my problem. I'm trying to get the sum and average from a column, but everything I see is getting sum and average from a row.

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT product_name,unit_cost,units,total,SUM(total),AVG(total)
FROM products
GROUP BY product_name,unit_cost,total
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

It returns the exact same amounts. What I need is to add all values in the unit_cost column and return the SUM and AVG of all its values. What am I missing? What did I not understand? Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: What would be the expected SUM and AVG if you run it on every individual product?

Comment: @Filburt Good question. The expected SUM and AVG are what it shows I suppose. After all, the average of 2 is 2, 4 is 4. The question is how do I add the prices of every item (SUM) and then get its average (AVG). Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

`AVG` and `SUM` as [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) and no grouping will do the job.

```sql
select product_name,unit_cost,units,total,
       SUM(total) over all_rows as sum_of_all_rows,
       AVG(total) over all_rows as avg_of_all_rows
from products
window all_rows as ();
```

Comment: Hey Stefanov.sm, that's some very strange syntax. First time I've seen... I definitely have to look into that! I'm still not getting the exact result though. For example, the SUM of unit_cost column is 33.79 and the AVG is 4.22. However, your method worked for the total column. 

Another example is an employee table with, say, 10 employee records. They would have a salary column, and I'd like to calculate the AVG of all their salaries combined. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, this is the usual syntax actually. Please note that `all_rows` is not a syntax element but just the name of a window definition for readability - `()` - no partitioning, i.e. for all. What's wrong with `unit_cost` column? I am sure that the method will work for it exactly the same as for `total`.

Answer (score 0):

The groups in your query contain just one row if total is a distinct value. This seems to be the case with your example. You can check this with a count aggregate (value = 1).

Removing `total` and probably `unit_cost`) from your select and group by clause should help.

Comment: Hey, clemens. I'm not sure if I follow your answer. I updated my question and added the units column. Total represents unit_price * units. I hope that makes sense. Thanks for chiming in!